# What is the license of the documentation at "https://git-scm.org/docs"

Tags: commercial, documentation, git

I would like to reuse some descriptions from https://git-scm.com/docs/ in my own Git instructions manual. This manual will be used commercially.

I have found a license for the "Pro Git" book [CC-By-NC-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/) but this is different content than the Git command line reference.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are asking us to hunt down the license status of a particular work. Please see the [help/on-topic] for acceptable topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The man pages of Git are under the same license as Git, e.g. GPL 2.0 (and v2.0 only: this is the same as the Linux kernel license)